# NullPointerException when trying to push InputEvent into ArrayDeque

Tags: java, io, nullpointerexception

I'm fairly new to Java and seriously rusty at strict C-like languages, so I can't seem to wrap my head around this issue:

```
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;
import java.util.ArrayDeque;

class DataBase
{
    private ArrayDeque<InputEvent> inputEvents;
    private static final DataBase instance = new DataBase();

    private DataBase() {}

    public InputEvent pollEventStack()
    {
        return inputEvents.poll();
    }

    public boolean pushToEventStack(InputEvent event)
    {
        boolean result = false;
        try {
            result = inputEvents.add(event);
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            Debug.log(event.paramString()); // We end up here with valid data in the log. Event is not as null as it claims to be, huh?

            System.exit(0);
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static DataBase getInstance()
    {
        return instance;
    }
}
```

If interested, here's the actual string I get in the log:

```
KEY_PRESSED,keyCode=27,keyText=Escape,keyChar=Escape,keyLocation=KEY_LOCATION_STANDARD,rawCode=27,primaryLevelUnicode=27,scancode=1,extendedKeyCode=0x1b
```

I'm sure it's something ridiculously simple I'm missing, unfortunately search yields no constructive results.

*P.S.: As a sidenote, is having a global-ish singleton storage bin for all my entities even a good idea? InputEvents are probably best off in their own class, but this should store gfx resources, enemies, items, etc in the long run. Or should it?*

Comment: By the way, did you mean to use an ArrayDeque, or were you aiming for a simple ArraList?

Comment: @drvdijk Considering this is a simple action stack for key and mouse events, all I need is push and pop capability. I'm not sure if ArrayDeque is the right way to go. As I said, Java is new to me.

Comment: @drvdijk Oh yes, and variable size is probably needed as well. Can't hog up the entire memory with a huge buffer or have too low a limit on stored events. The deque appears adequate for that. Any downsides I'm missing?

Comment: A Deque might just be suitable. I merely asked because that would't directly be the first Collection type a new Java person would use to start off with. It really depends on what you want to do with it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`event` is indeed not null, `inputEvents` is, it has not been initialized. You can either initialize it in the field specification (`private ArrayDequeue<InputEvent> inputEvents = new ArrayDequeue<InputEvent>();`) or in the constructor.

Comment: Ugh... I **knew** it's that simple. Feeling like a fool now. Thanks for the prompt answer. (Can accept answer only in 7 minutes)

Comment: That's all right, that's what StackOverflow is for, right? If this answered your question, you could accept it :)

Comment: Yep, accepted, of course. Sorry for the delay, SO limits. By the way, do you have an opinion on the footnote question? Can't ask it separately. :)

Comment: In the light of OO design, I'd say a single storage bin for all objects is not a good idea. Create a nice object model, and store all instances in there. You could nevertheless create some singleton lookup registries for some specific types (EnemiesRegistry?).

Comment: Multiple said storage bins? Not sure it's better than a central directory (I'm from php+mysql background, this is mysql-inspired). Some entities need to be accessible by multiple manager classes: graphics, sound, physics, AI, etc. So it's either several singletons or one central. Unless I want a nightmare of parameter chains...